# Add XML Attribute from a CSV file

Tags: xml, csv, powershell-5.0

I've looked for a while and haven't found anything specific to what I'm trying to do. I've been working in Powershell 5.1 as I have a basic knowledge of it (beginner knowledge really). I'm working with Phrases.xml and Language.csv

Phrases.xml contains just attributes for phrases that I would like to add a different language to. The row ID is specific to the program, so I can't create an XML from scratch unfortunately (I think I would have had an easier time figuring that out).

```
<Localise Column="Care.Role" RowID="2" Default="Bathroom" Culture="English" />
```

What I need to add is a new attribute (Local) and change an existing (Culture):

```
<Localise Column="Care.Role" RowID="2" Default="Bathroom" Local="Baño" Culture="Spanish" />
```

I have a CSV file with the Default and Spanish rows like:

```
English,Spanish
Bathroom,Baño
```

I've been able to read attributes from the file and import a csv file into Powershell, but now I'm pretty stuck on how to actually bring it all together. My poor attempt to figure this out:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Phrases.xml' 
$Csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\Language.csv 
$doc = (Get-Content -Path $path)

$Csv.English | ForEach-Object { 
$attribute = $doc.CreateAttribute("Local") 
$attribute.Value = $Csv.Spanish 
$doc.Localise.Append($attribute) 
} 
$xml.Save("C:\Users\me\Desktop\fsox.xml")
```

This gives me this error for every line in my csv:
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'CreateAttribute'.
At line:6 char:1
+ $attribute = $doc.CreateAttribute("Local")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Exception setting "Value": "Cannot set a value on node type 'Element'."
At line:7 char:1
+ $attribute.Value = $Csv.Translate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterSetValue

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:8 char:1
+ $doc.Localise.Append($attribute)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

I haven't quite figured out the correct way to add an attribute much less change the Culture. Any help would be vastly appreciated.

Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: I've been working at this and changed to the following:

Comment: $path = 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Phrases.xml'
$Csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\Language.csv
$doc = [xml] (Get-Content -Path $path)

$Csv.English | ForEach-Object {
    $doc.root.Localise.setattribute
    ("Local","$CsvSpanish")
    }
$doc.Save("C:\Users\jgotcher\Desktop\fsox.xml")

I'm still having trouble so it'll run, but the way I structured it I don't think it adds to XML correctly. My save at the end is just an original copy of Phrases.xml